# Combining PHP and HTML div

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an error message within a a Captcha Form when the user enters the wrong code:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){ ?>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF; padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:180px;">Wrong verification code</div><br /> 
<?php ;}?>
```

Another php file sends the result of the captcha code check back in the 'wrong_code' parameter.

When I save and run the file as a .php file it operates perfectly, however I am stuck using html/htm files (due to many years of Google knowing these files) and the html/htm files show the above div upon loading.

I have tried modifying .htaccess by adding various iterations of the statements below to get the html files to act more PHP. this did not work:

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
 AddHandler php-script .php .html
```

I am operating on a form with very little space so I just want an error message that opens up a line under the captcha box in red to tell the user the code is wrong. Where am I going wrong? Should I be doing this another way?

All help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The code I am using is:
<?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){ ?>
<div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF; padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:180px;">Wrong verification code</div><br /> 
<?php ;}?>

I want there to be no error message upon loading and for the error message to show only if the wrong_code parameter is sent back to the web page.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this in your .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php
```

Edit: doing this would mean you'd need to convert your .html files to .php files
Which you can do with a PHP file:

```
<?php
    $files = scandir(getcwd());
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'html'){
            rename($file, pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME) .'php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: That would just create a 404 error, since his files are `.htm`/`.html` already. What is he has thousands of files? He's not going to rename them all to `.php`

Comment: @scrowler Good call. Edited and added a PHP file that will do that.

Comment: That was totally not what I was suggesting. -1